# Looking for a software to save the last recorded minutes

Tags: video, c#

on behalf of my company I am looking for a very specific type of software. Maybe you'll have any recommendations.

Software requirements:

- low weight on performance
- perm screen record with the possibility to save the last X minutes
- Usable from C# WPF code

To give you a few information why I am looking for such a software:

Some customers faces issues which can not be replicated. To help to find the issue we want to implement a function to save a record of the last actions.

I am looking forward to hear your recommendations.

Greetings,
SirCodiac

Comment: That's a smart way of debugging.

Answer (score 0):

It appears what you require is the ability to continuously save video so that the new data overwrites the oldest data. This way, you will always have the recent captured video, without needing infinite storage space.
The company I work for has a multimedia SDK that contains a [DVR module](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia/dvr). This module uses circular buffers to save video, with the ability to copy any part of that video for permanent storage. You can configure the number and size of these buffers to determine how much data to keep at any time, based on how much you need and how much storage space you have.
The toolkit also contains a Screen Capture video source that can be used with DVR module.

There’s a WPF C# demo project that uses both screen capture and DVR to Continuously capture then save last N minutes of video. You can find it here:
[HOW TO: Continuously capture then save last N minutes of video](https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/t12819-)

The toolkit has a free evaluation you can try before deciding whether to buy, which includes free technical support during the trial. [You can download the evaluation here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=mm).